# How to create re-send verification code system in Django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a problem and that is whenever a user creates her/his account and doesn't enter her/his code(it means the code is expired) the user can't get code again because the account can be created once. I want to know how can I change this code to work in a way that the user can get the verification code again and again.
serilizer.py:

```py
class RegisterationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True, help_text=_("Enter a valid password"))
    repeated_password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True, help_text=_("Enter your password again"))
    
    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["email", "username", "name", "password", "repeated_password"]
        extra_kwargs = {
            'email': {'help_text': _("Enter your email")},
            'username': {'help_text': _("Enter your username")},
            'name': {'help_text': _("Enter your name"), 'required': False, 'allow_blank': True},
        }

    
    def validate(self, data):
        print(User.objects.filter(email=data["email"], is_active=False))
        if data["password"] and data["repeated_password"] and data["password"] != data["repeated_password"]:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(_("Password and repeated password must be the same"))
        if data["email"].strip() == data["username"].strip():
            raise serializers.ValidationError(_("Email and username must be different")) 
        return data

class ConfirmCodeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(write_only=True, max_length=220, min_length=6, help_text=_("Enter your email"))
    class Meta:
        model = VerficationCode
        fields = ["email","code"]
        extra_kwargs = {
            'email': {'help_text': _("Enter your email")},
            'code': {'help_text': _("Enter your code")},
        }
```

views.py:

```py
class RegisterationApiView(APIView):
    """
    Get username, email, name, and password from the user
    and save it in the database
    """
    def post(self, request):
        if request.user.is_anonymous:
            data = RegisterationSerializer(data=request.data) 
            if data.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
                validated_data = data.validated_data
                del(validated_data["repeated_password"])
                user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)  
                verification_code = give_code()
                VerficationCode.objects.create(user=user, code=verification_code)
                send_mail("Verification Code", f"your code is: {verification_code}", "nima@gmail.com", [data.validated_data["email"]])
                return Response({
                "message": f'{data.validated_data["email"]} account was created successfully, your verification code has been sent to your email'
                }, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            
            else:
                return Response(data.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        else:
            return Response({
                "message": "You're already authorized"
            }, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST) 

class ConfirmCodeApiView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        data = ConfirmCodeSerializer(data=request.data)
        if data.is_valid():
            user = User.objects.get(email=data.validated_data["email"])
            if user.is_active:
                return Response({
                    "message": "Your account is already confirmed"
                }, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
            else:
                code = VerficationCode.objects.get(user=user)
                if code.code == data.validated_data["code"] and VerficationCode.objects.nonexpired().filter(user=user).exists():
                    user.is_active = True
                    user.save()
                    return Response({
                        "message": "Your account has been confirmed"
                    }, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
                else:
                    return Response({
                        "message": "Your code is incorrect or expired"
                    }, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        else:
            return Response(data.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new field(column) to your user Model :

```
 email_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

upon registering check if the given email already exists in your database or not .
if it doesn't exists , it would be a common registration but if it does, check if email_verified is True or False .

if it's True then the registration will raise a bad request as email already exists but if it's false , then the user didn't use the code to verify his account .

send verification code again under this circumstance . so every time a user tries to register this procedure will lead to a correct registration flow.

i hope this helped .